# displaying array data in react. output is not coming

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks

when I am printing `console.log(response.data)` in console below output is coming.

[image]

I created one hook
const [result,setResult] = useState([]);

and then output of API I set as

```
setResult(response.data);
```

when I am writing below code it is just printing `" Data is"`. it is not printing output of `result`

```
              <h1>
                  Data is
               {
                   result.map((res:any)=>{
                       {res.id};
                   })
                }    

              </h1>
```

what mistake I am doing?

Comment: a lot of things can be wrong since you didn't provide enough code segment but from what's given, the map is not properly used. You need to ```return res.id```. Try something like this ```result.map((res) => res.id)``` considering the fact you only want id of each element

Comment: can you supply the full relevant code?

Comment: thank you araf. I actually want to print all the element. the code you suggested is working for id. but if I open bracked and put res.id; res.name then nothing is getting printted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole logic of your code it's okay. You are using the `useState` Hook correctly. And the data your passing to the state is an array which will work fine with the `map()` method. The only problem I'm seeing is that your `map()` method is not well implemented.

Try this instead:

```
<h1>
  Data is
  {
   result.map((res:any)=>{
      return <p>{res.id}</p>
   })
  }    
</h1>
```

The `map()` method always returns something. When it is a one liner it is not necessary to type return.

```
<h1>
  Data is
  {
   result.map((res:any) => res.id )
  }    
</h1>
```

To print multiple properties of the object:

```
<h1>
  Data is
  {
   result.map((res:any) => {
      return (
        <div key={res.id}>
           <p>{res.id}</p>
           <p>{res.name}</p>
           <p>{res.createdAt}</p>
        </div>
      )
   })
  }    
</h1>
```

Comment: actually it is perfectly working. let support along with Id I need to print name so I am writing res=>{res.id ; res.name} then it is not printing anything.

Comment: can you suggest how I can print other values like name , createdAt along with id, please.

Comment: `return <p>{res.id}</p>` surely.

Comment: thank you Andy, I think I am still making some mistake.                  <h1>
  Data is
  {
   result.map((res:any) =>{
 return(
   <p>res.id</p>
   <p>res.userId</p>
 )
})
  }    
</h1>

Comment: @ShrutiSharma Sorry I forgot to add curly braces to the first code snippet. Add curly braces to the variables  `<h1> Data is { result.map((res:any) =>{ return( <p>{res.id}</p> <p>{res.userId}</p> ) }) } </h1>` and also, wrap the return elements with a parent div

Comment: I added a new code snippet, try it out.

Comment: Great to hear! keep it up